# Расположение форм

Tags: html, css

У меня есть 3 формы ввода логин-пароль-емэил, к ним подключены css. Нужно расположить их по центру страницы один за другим. Вижу 2 проблемы—в подключении стилей ко всем трем в 1 документе и организация самого расположения форм на странице. Помогите советом пожалуйста.
На картинке в редакторе их соединил.
[image: 1]

Comment: Что значит - "в подключении стилей ко всем трем в 1 документе" ?

Comment: я имею ввиду, как мне в одном документе расположить 3 формы с разными стилями?

Comment: Оберните их в разные классы?

Comment: Извиняюсь туплю, из 3 css можно сделать 1